# What does the $q$-Catalan Numbers count?

Tags: catalan-numbers, q-analogs, co.combinatorics

I had completed a paper describing the $q$-Catalan numbers, which is the $q$-analog of the Catalan numbers.

The $n$-th Catalan numbers can be represented by:

$$C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n}$$

and with the recurrence relation:

$$C_{n+1}=\sum^n_{i=0}C_i C_{n-i}\ \ \ \ \ \forall n\geq 0$$

Now, for the $q$-analog, I know the definition of that can be defined as:

$$\lim_{q\to 1}\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}=n$$

and we know that the definition of the $q$-analog, can be defined like this:

$$[n]_q=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}=1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots+q^{n-1}$$

which this is the $q$-analog of $n$.

and that for that $q$-analog of ${2n\choose n}$:

$$C_n(q)=\frac{1}{[n+1]_q}\begin{bmatrix}2n\\ n\end{bmatrix}_q$$

**So, everything up to this point I know what I'm doing, and I'm not sure if I did everything correct after this**

So, in order to generate the $q$-Catalan Numbers, I will need to use the Lagrange inversion formula.

And, then I got something like this:

$$G(X)=\sum^\infty_{i=0}C_i x^i$$

where $G(x)$ is the generating function, and that

$$G(x)=G_q(x)=\sum^\infty_{i=0}C_n(q)x^n=\sum^\infty_{i=0}C_nx^n=1+x+x^2(1+q)+\cdots$$

Since I know that for Catalan Numbers, it's true:

$$G(x)=(G(x))^2+1$$

So, the $q$-analog will just be:

$$G_q(x)=G(x)G_q(x)+1$$

So the recurrence relation for the $q$-analog Catalan Numbers:

$$C_{n+1}(q)=\sum^n_{i=0}C_i C_{n-1}q^i$$

**It just doesn't sound right here...**

Also, I don't have a clue that what does the $q$-Catalan Numbers count, can anyone help me with that or give me like a clue?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Off topic up to the last line for asking others to check your work for you, and off topic after that for asking others to do your googling for you.

Comment: and I don't think there is such a thing as 'the' q-analog

Comment: I'm not sure the $q$-Catalan numbers "count things", since they are not integers

Comment: @Adrien Hardy: They might still have enumerative significance. For example, the $q$-binomial coefficient ${n\brack k}_q$, when $q$ is specialized to a prime power, counts the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$.

Comment: Does  http://www.math.upenn.edu/~jhaglund/books/qtcat.pdf Theorem 1.6 help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Vasu commented already: there is not "the" q-analogue of the Catalan numbers. And indeed, you're mixing two different here.

- Your first q-Catalan numbers defined by the $q$-binomials is MacMahon's q-Catalan numbers which is (and I don't actually know many others) the **major index generating function** on Dyck paths, where the descent set is given by the positions of the valleys.
- Your second $q$-Catalan numbers given by the recurrence is, on the other hand, the **area generating function** on Dyck paths.

Both are deeply related in the context of the $q,t$-Catalan numbers appearing in the theory of symmetric function as a bigraded Hilber series of (the alternating part of) the **space of diagonal coinvariants**.

As Darij mentions, both (and as well the $q,t$-Catalan numbers and the space of diagonal coinvariants) can be found e.g. in Jim Haglund's book [http://www.math.upenn.edu/~jhaglund/books/qtcat.pdf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ejhaglund/books/qtcat.pdf). You actually find quite a bit as well in our online project http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000012 and http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000027.

Comment: I just remembered that I gave a link to another statistic that gives MacMahon's $q$-Catalan numbers here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93136/enumerative-meaning-of-natural-q-catalan-numbers/93980#93980