# Proof of certain $q$-identity for $q$-Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergeometric-functions, q-analogs, catalan-numbers

Let us use the standard notation for $q$-integers, $q$-binomials,
and the $q$-analog 
$$
\operatorname{Cat}_q(n) := \frac{1}{[n+1]_q} \left[\matrix{2n \\ n}\right]_q.
$$
I want to prove that for all integers $n\geq 0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cat}_q(n+2)
=
\sum_{0\leq j,k \leq n}
q^{k(k+2) + j(n+2)}
\left[\matrix{n \\ 2k}\right]_q
\operatorname{Cat}_q(k)
\frac{[n+4]_q}{[k+2]_q}
\left[\matrix{n-2k \\ j}\right]_q.
\end{equation}

I have tried quite a bit, but not succeeded. Using $q$-hypergeometric series,
this is equivalent with proving
$$
\sum_{\substack{k\geq 0 \\ j \geq 0}}
q^{k(k+2)+j(n+2)}
\frac{
(q;q)_{n+4}
}{
(q^{n+3};q)_{n+2} (q;q)_{j}
}
\frac{
(q^{n-2k+1};q)_{2k}
(q^{n-2k-j+1};q)_{j}
}{
(q;q)_{k}
(q;q)_{k+2}
}
=1
$$
which I have also not managed to prove.
I believe that some WZ-method could solve this easily,
but a human-friendly proof would be preferrable. 
Note that the identity above is very similar to a 
theorem by Andrews (see reference below). It states that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Cat}_q(n+1)
=
\sum_{k \geq 0}
q^{k(k+2)}
\left[\matrix{n \\ 2k}\right]_q
\operatorname{Cat}_q(k)
\frac{(-q^{k+2};q)_{n-k}}{(-q;q)_k}.
\end{equation}

UPDATE: I have managed to find a more 
general conjecture, which would imply the one above.
It states that for integer $n \geq 0$, and general $a,c$,
we have
$$
 \sum_{s}
 \frac{ (-a q^n)^{s}
q^{-\binom{s}{2}}
(q^{-n};q)_{s} }{  (q;q)_{s}  } 
{}_{2}\phi_{1}(cq^{s-1}/a,q^{-s};c;q,q)
=
\frac{ (ac ;q)_{n}  }{ (c;q)_{n} }.
$$

I use [This book](http://www.fuchs-braun.com/media/e4ef05831b027c9cffff8033ffffffef.pdf) as my main reference for notation and identities.

*Andrews, George E.*, [**(q)-Catalan identities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-6263-8_10), Alladi, Krishnaswami (ed.) et al., The legacy of Alladi Ramakrishnan in the mathematical sciences. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4419-6262-1/hbk; 978-1-4419-6263-8/ebook). 183-190 (2010). [ZBL1322.11018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1322.11018).

Comment: Is there a human-friendly proof for the non-$q$ analog of this identity? That might be a start.

Comment: Yes, there is a combinatorial interpretation, tusing triangulations. I'll get the reference later today.

Comment: Here is the combinatorial interpretation Per is talking about: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82091698.pdf

Comment: If one takes $q=1$, makes the change of variables $n \to n-4$ and $k \to k-2$ and sum over all $j$, one obtains the formula in the article. The summands the number of triangulations of regular $(n+2)$-gons with $k$ ears (an ear is a triangle on the vertices $i$, $i+1$ and $i+2$, where the indices are taken modulo $n+2$.

Comment: Is it possible that the triangulation interpretation of the $q=1$ identity is compatible with the statistic on triangulations discussed here?: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93136/enumerative-meaning-of-natural-q-catalan-numbers

Comment: @SamHopkins you mean, if the bijection is compatible? I have not tried but that would be nice... although such a proof is much stronger than what we need for our paper....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem,
in the last general conjecture, one can apply the $q$-Chu-Vandermonde theorem. After some simplification,
the resulting expression can be expressed as a ${}_2\phi_1$ q-hypergeometric series, where one again can apply the $q$-Chu-Vandermonde theorem.

Skipping lots of details the proof still requires a few pages - it can now be found [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11157) (Thm. 57)